# Question about continuity of functions in a topology

Tags: general-topology

For the following question written below, what I would like to ask is, are the open set from an ordered topology $\mathcal{U}$ of a linearly ordered set $Y.$  The reason I ask is that to answer the question, if I want to use the open set definition for continuity, I have to specify what the open sets are specifically.

Let $(Y,\leq)$ be a linearly ordered set, and let $\mathcal{U}$ denote the order topology on $Y$.  Furthermore, let $(X,\mathcal{F})$ be a topological space and let $f,g:X\rightarrow\ Y$ be continuous functions.

Define a function $h:X \rightarrow\ Y$ by $h(x)=\min\{f(x),g(x)\}$ for all $\ x\in\ X$.  Prove that $h$ is continuous.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't quite know what to make of the sentence "are the open set(s?) from an oreder**ed** topology" et cetera. They are from the *order topology*, and while topologies inherit the partial order from the power set of the underlying space, that notion is not particularly useful here.

Comment: I read the sentence " are the open set from an ordered topology $\mathcal{U}$ of a linearly ordered set $Y.$" five times now, and I still don't understand what it means.

Comment: $5xum, I am confused over how to defined the open sets from an ordered topology when the said ordered topology is on a linearly ordered set.  Sorry for my confuse wording.

Comment: $Gae. S , My apologies for the confusing wording.  I am just confused over how to specific the open set from the topology U when the underlying set is a linearly ordered set.

Comment: Is your question:  what is the order topology?

Comment: @Randall, I know what the basis elements, open sets, for an order topology is.  But the underlying set Y is a linearly order set.  How would that affect what the open sets for the order topology?

Comment: @SethMai because the basic open sets depend on the particular ordering on $Y$.

Comment: @Randall, I am not sure then how would the open sets in a base for the ordered topology on a linearly order set be different from any other subsets from the same linearly ordered set.  I mean is ordered the same as linearly ordered?

Comment: Then I do not understand your question.

Comment: @Randall, we are given an ordered topology, and a linearly ordered set.  The topology is on the linearly ordered set.  What is an example of an open sets for this topology $\mathcal{U}$ look like?  Also, what is the differences between an ordered relation and a totally ordered relation?

Comment: Cant you use the pasting lemma ?

Comment: @PedroSantos, sorry for my late reply.  I am not sure if I could.  I know if I know what the open sets look like, i can solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $y\in Y$ let $(-,y)=\{y'\in Y: y'<y\}$  and $(y,+)=\{y'\in y:y<y'\}.$

Let $L=\{(-,y):y\in Y\}$ and $U=\{(y,+):y \in Y\}.$

Let $B=\{Y\} \cup L \cup U \cup \{l\cap u:l\in L\land u\in U\}.$

Then $B$ is a base for the order-topology on $Y. $

For $y,y'\in Y$ let $(y,y')=\{y''\in Y: y<y''<y'\}.$ This is called a bounded open interval. The members of $\{l\cap u:l\in L\land u\in U\}$ are the bounded open intervals (including the empty set).

Any $A\subset Y$ is convex iff $\forall a,a'\in A\; (\,(a,a')\subset A).$The members of the base $B$ are precisely the convex open sets in the order-topology. So any open set  in the order-topology is the union of a family of convex open sets.

This is applicable to all $Y,$ i.e. regardless of whether $Y$ has a max or min or any other specific properties. In particular (as a caution)  it is possible for a bounded open interval to have a max or min.

A useful property for any $Y$ is that the closure of $(-,y)$ is $(-,y)\cup \{y\}$ iff $y=\sup (-,y)$ iff $(-,y)$ is not empty and has no max. And $(-,y)$ is closed iff $(-,y)$  is empty or has a largest member. And similar considerations hold for $(y,+).$

From that, we see that if $y\in Y$ and $y\not \in A\subset Y$ then $y\in \overline A$ iff $[\,y=\sup (A\cap (-,y)) \lor y=\inf (A\cap (y,+)\,)\,].$

Comment: sorry for my late reply.  Thank you very much for clearing up my confusion.  Much appreciated.

Comment: In General Topology by R. Engelking, he uses $(y,\to)$ for my $(y,+)$.... I find it irritating that although  I can  type (y,\to  ) to get $(y,\to )$ but for $(\leftarrow, y)$  I must type (\leftarrow, y) because there is no \from